# Remove iphone 3G and ipod touch 3 from the target

Tags: iphone

How does one remove the iphone 3G and the ipod touch 3 from the target?

I have an app that uses libraries that need armv6, so cannot remove that from the architectures. Is it possible to still exclude the iphone 3G and the ipod touch 3?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**NB:** I've assumed you also don't wish to include devices lower than those that you've specified, i.e. ipod2.

It's **not possible** to remove devices individually from your application, but it is possible to restrict what your application requires in an attempt to restrict devices.

I can't think of anything that works exactly if you need to maintain armv6, but if you can think of something that the devices you want to include have that the devices you want to exclude haven't, you can add those items to the **Required Device Capabilities** in your **Info.plist**.

**Open-GLES 2.0** might be a good starter think to require as the iPhone 3G has Open-GLES 1.1.

If you tell us a little more about *why* you want to exclude these devices, I might be able to provide a more elaborate answer.

Comment: does this Open-GLES 2.0 setting remove the ipod touch 3rd gen?

Comment: Not certain. I don't think so. You might have to find something else for the iPod

Comment: What is it that you are trying to exclude? There might be a cleaner solution

Comment: I just want to exclude the iphone 3G and the ipod touch 3rd and below